# Autotest runs only once if tests don't fail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, autotest

I'm struggling with setting up autotest. The problem is that it will only run once if the tests are green. I don't yet have any filesystem-notification plugin added yet (autotest-inotify is what I intend to add eventually). When the tests are red, it will run continously like it should, but on green it will just hang. I can't interrupt it via Ctrl-C like I normally can.

Version info:

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09 revision 32553) [x86_64-linux]
$ which ruby
/home/sztomi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby
$ gem search autotest

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

autotest (4.4.6)
autotest-rails (4.1.1)
$ autotest
loading autotest/rails_rspec2
/home/sztomi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby -rrubygems -S /home/sztomi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tut/gems/rspec-core-2.6.4/bin/rspec --tty (...)
```

My ~/.autotest is empty.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any settings in ~/.autotest or .autotest in your project? There might be some clues there.

Comment: I forgot to mention that it's empty.